# Limits of translation of a multi-lingual website

Tags: html, seo, title, translate

I've tried to search around the internet for some documentation on what I should translate on my multi-lingual website.

I understand that most elements that are easy to read for visitors should be translated. However, Google Bots and such, will also read what visitors usually dont even catch up on.

Here is one example:

```
<a href="#" title="Go to frontage">Home</a>
```

Most people will undoubtedly read `Home` in this case, but is it necessary to also translate the `title`?

If so, what elements should I translate, and what should I not?

Also, is the language in the `html` tag necessary for localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most people will undoubtedly read Home in this case, but is it necessary to also translate the title?

If you aren't expecting people to read it, don't provide it at all.

But certainly don't dump random bits of English into a document written in another language.

> If so, what elements should I translate, and what should I not?

Translate the entire document.

> Also, is the language in the html tag necessary for localization?

The `lang` attribute is useful for a number of things (such as allowing a screen reader to trigger the correct pronunciation dictionary). Include it if you know what language the document is written in.